# is it possible to execute C code during C++ stack unwinding / exception

Tags: c, exception, gcc

I need to write a C library which will be integrated into a C++ code base. This library may call C++ code passed as a callback. These functions may throw C++ exceptions.

I'd like to ensure that the cleanup code is run during the stack unwinding process. I could use the `cleanup` attribute to ensure that:

> If -fexceptions is enabled, then cleanup_function is run during the stack unwinding that happens during the processing of the exception.

From the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html).

Unfortunately I can't use the cleanup attribute. I'd like to register the cleanup function to be run during stack unwinding programmatically using portable C.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why C? If you write the new library - write it in C++. Any specific reason?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Sorry. Ideally both.

Comment: as @P__J__ - metioned why in C? but if you insist and you have your own reasons c++ always can execute C code. just use the `extern "C" {
   void your_c_function();
}` savedkeyword.

Comment: Depending on your reson options may include running the codebases in different processes and using ipc between them.

Comment: I'm dynamically generating the code, that is why it needs to be C. I could make the compiler accept C++, but it would be a major change.

Comment: You should go for pure C. Calling C++ from C is UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to register the cleanup function to be run during stack unwinding programmatically using portable C.

### Not possible in *portable* C.

The C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) does not even require any [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and permit [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) not using it. In *some* cases, there is no "stack unwinding". Think of [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimizations (try `gcc -Wall -O3 -S -fverbose-asm` with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and read [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report explaining *some* `gcc` optimizations (work in progress in June 2020). If you think of C++, read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf),  its C++11 standard.

However, if you decide to use (specifically) a recent enough [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (so [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) in June 2020) you could consider using specific builtins or pragmas. GCC has a chapter about [C language extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) and another one on [C++ extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) and also one about [invoking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) it.

You might even be interested in writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html), or in using its [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or in reusing its [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) by Ian Taylor.

On Linux, see also [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) and consider using [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/).

You could ask some help from e.g. [AdaCore](https://www.adacore.com/) or [on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-help/) public mailing list.